# Имя типа или пространства имен "Net" отсутствует в пространстве имен

Tags: c#

Всем привет...

Когда я в Microsoft Visual C# Express пишу `using System.Net` или `using System.Timers`,
то мне выдает ошибку:

> Имя типа или пространства имен "Net" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System" и т.д.

Скажите мне, это что значит я не смогу написать такие программы в Visual Express или как-то можно написать?

Comment: Уточните, какие ссылки(references) в проекте у вас есть. Скорее всего в это проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В проекте должна быть ссылка на System. На панели меню: 
Проект (Project) -> Добавить ссылку (Add reference) -> вкладка .Net -> System

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить ссылку (reference) на сборку system.net